# How to import correctly class in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'd like to `import` `module` from other`js`,I tried like following.

But I caught following error.

`uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

at `import Test from 'test.js';`

`import Test from 'test.js';` doesn't seems to have syntax error..

What is the cause of this error

`main.js`

```
(()=>{

      import Test from 'test.js';  
    
      const url = "/quiz-data";
            
      fetch(url)
      .then(json => { const quiz = new Quiz(json); })
      .then(quiz => displayQuiz(quiz,1))

})();
```

`test.js`

```
class Test {

    constructor(quizData){
        this._quizzes = quizData.results;
        this._correctAnswersNum = 0;
    }
    
    getNumOfQuiz(){
        return this._quizzes.length;
    }
    
    getCategory(index){
        return this._quizzes[index-1].category;
    }
}
module.exports = Test;
```

Comment: You cannot have an `import`  statement inside a function. Drop the IIFE wrapper, it is not necessary when using modules.

Answer (score 0):

1. Import has to be defined outside the function
2. For your import to work, export the class as follows

   `export default class Test { ... }`

Comment: Thans I suffered `SyntaxError: Unexpected token export` I guess this was done in node.js.. I confused how to fix it,, thanks

Comment: @Heisenberg `import` can only be used with `export`. you need to `require` if you use `module.exports`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import the module with es6 syntax (`import Test from "test"`) you need to export the module with the same approach:

```
export default Test.
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to use `module.exports` it's used for `common.js` imports. Most commonly used in `node.js`.

If you want to keep it you can do following:

```
// test.js
module.exports = Test;

// main.js
require('./test.js');
```

This is in case you have a node.js project.

If you want to use es6 modules you need to do following:

```
// test.js
export default Test;

// main.js
import Test from './test';
```

**Make sure the import and export are not wrapped in the function**.

In this case each file is treated as a module and you don't need to wrap your code into IIFE.